# PY Charm not loading module

Tags: python, module, pycharm

I am trying to install `pycrypto` to my pycharm, and every time I install it says that I have installed it correctly. I made sure to do so by going into settings and clicking the + button. But when I try to `import pycrypto` it is giving me an error that the module does not exist. I have been trying, and its really frustrating at this point.

I also tried adding `https://pypi.python.org/pypi as a repository.` as a repo but whenever I add it and click OK the repository disappears when I go back into the + window

Comment: you don't install a python module in pycharm, pycharm is an IDE... you install it with your interpreter installation, if it doesn't show up in the list of items available to your interpreter it isn't going to be found by anything.  this boils down to IDE troubleshooting which is outside the preview of a proper SO question.

Comment: Yes I know that, I am trying to install the packages via interpreter , this is what I mentioned in the settings and adding the + button

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your Question with the used Version's:

   > OS Version, Python Version, pyCharm Version, Missing Module Version
2. Update your Question with the Output of

   > For single Python setup or Python 2.x
   >   `pip show <Name of the failed Module>`
   >
   > > **Expexted Output**:
   > >     `# pip show pycrypto
   > >
   > >     \---
   > >     Name: pycrypto
   > >     Version: 2.6.1
   > >     Location: /opt/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
   > >     Requires:`
   >
   > For Python 3.x
   >   `pip3 show <Name of the missing Module>`